# NSData file type validation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, web-services, macos, nsdata

I'm consuming a web service that should return a wav file. I capture the result in an NSData object and save it to the local documents director.

How do I verify that the data is indeed a wav before saving it? If there were an error on the server, it may return a long string of HTML garbage.

Thanks!

```
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:RequestURL 
                                                        cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy 
                                                    timeoutInterval:30.0];

NSHTTPURLResponse* response = nil;
NSData *soundData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req  returningResponse:&response error:&error];

//save voicemail file locally
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *destPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"returned.wav"];
[fileManager createFileAtPath:destPath contents:soundData attributes:nil];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is 2 way to do this (hope that one of them will be acceptable for you):

1) check NSHTTPURLResponse's statusCode (type NSInteger) (should be equal to 200, if everything is ok),

2) check NSHTTPURLResponse's MIME type (type NSString *) (if I'm not wrong, should be @"audio/vnd.wave")

Comment: +1 any error response from a server should have a response in the 400 or 500 range.

Comment: Because the request may be "successful" from the server standpoint, checking the MIME type is the ideal way.  Thank you!

Comment: Final Code:
    NSHTTPURLResponse* response = nil;
 
    NSData *soundData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req  returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    //save voicemail file locally
    NSDictionary *headers = [response allHeaderFields];
    NSString *contentType = (NSString *)[headers objectForKey:@"Content-Type"];
    if ([contentType isEqual:@"audio/x-wav"])
 NSLog(@"it's a wav file!");
    else
 NSLog(@"unexpected response type: %@", contentType);